# Remove nests more than 3 sonar violation

Tags: python

I have a String like below

```
line="10,20,30,40,100-200,500,1000-10000"
```

Iterate each value in the list and check for some if it is between min and max value and return False if not

Current code look like

```
for i in line.strip().split(','):
        if '-' not in i:
            if not 0 <= int(i) <= 50000:
                return False
        elif len(i.split('-')) == 2:
            for value in i.split('-'):
                if not 0<= int(value) <= 50000:
                    return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

I need to optimize it better to remove the nested if statements and more return statements.

Violation:

> Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 "if", "for", "while", "try"
>   and "with" statements.

I tried to extract to a different methods but for some permutations didn't work.
Thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of this `list.strip()`, basically list object has no attribute as `strip`

Comment: I assume that you don't have a `list` (not a Python list), but a string with stuff separated by commas.

Comment: If that's true, or if that's false, please explain more thoroughly what do you have, what do you want, and why are you doing it that way. I would use regular expressions instead of all that code.

Comment: @Its not list.Its string.

Comment: @MariusSiuram I have a string `"10,20,30,40,100-200,500,1000-10000"`.Spliting the string based on `,` and need to check if its between two values, if not return false else continue and return true .

Comment: thanks for the clarification and the edit. Now I understand the code's goal.

Comment: wait, the string `"50,10,80-40"` is a valid one? What about `"   1  ,  2,3 , 5 - 10"`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the inner `for` with a generator expression:

```
for i in list.strip().split(','):
        if '-' not in i:
            if not 0 <= int(i) <= 50000:
                return False
        elif len(i.split('-')) == 2:
            return all(0 <= int(value) <= 50000 for value in i.split('-'))
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine the first two `if`s, and get rid of the second `for` cycle since you only iterate over two elements. Also shouldn't `return True` be outside of the for loop. With the current code it will return `True` after it checks only the first integer (I am not sure if that's what you want)

```
for i in line.strip().split(','):
        if '-' not in i and not 0 <= int(i) <= 50000:
            return False
        elif '-' in i and len(i.split('-')) == 2 and not (0<= i.split('-')[0] <= 50000 and 0<= i.split('-')[1] <= 50000):
            return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Some nesting reductions could be achieved through:

```
for i in line.strip().split(','):
    if '-' not in i:
        return 0 <= int(i) <= 50000

    # The following will fail if there are more than one hyphen
    # if a different error should be thrown, try-catch it
    str_val1, str_val2 = i.split('-')
    value1, value2 = int(str_val1), int(str_val2)

    return 0 <= value1 <= value2 <= 50000
```